# Python: how to inherit from two classes?

Tags: python, django

First of all I'm a python newbie.

I'm playing with Django and I'm trying to extend some classes.

Now I'm in this situation:

I have a new class

```
customBaseModelAdmin(admin.options.BaseModelAdmin):
    #override a method of BaseModelAdmin
```

and I want to write another class

```
customModelAdmin(customBaseModelAdmin):
```

that obviously inherits `customBaseModelAdmin`, but that has the same methods of the standard `ModelAdmin`.
But, since the standard `ModelAdmin` inherits the standard `BaseModelAdmin`, how can I do?

I tried with the definition

```
class customModelAdmin(customBaseModelAdmin, admin.options.ModelAdmin):
```

but it doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks,

Giovanni

Comment: Why does it not work? If you get an error, please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let `customBaseModelAdmin` inherit from `ModelAdmin`. You can still override the method from `BaseModelAdmin`.

But of course it could be that `ModelAdmin` also overrides this method. I would take a look at the source code of these classes to really know what is going on there.

Comment: I already gave a look to the source code... I think your suggestion is right, but I have to find how to override in the right way....
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just subclass ModelAdmin for customBaseModelAdmin?

Comment: because I want to keep the original version of ModelAdmin (that is the one provided by Django).

Comment: @Giovanni Di Milia: Subclassing does not mean that the original class is destroyed ;)

Comment: Yes, but how can I subclass ModelAdmin for customBaseModelAdmin? I mean... can you make an example?

Comment: @Giovanni Di Milia: It is the same what I said in other words.

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
class customModelAdmin(customBaseModelAdmin):
    etc
```